# Why should io.ReadAll be avoided?

Tags: go

I have read some articles on avoiding `io.ReadAll` and preferring `io.Copy` over that. They mainly justify this suggestion by mentioning that `io.ReadAll` loads the whole `[]byte` out of the reader into the memory at once while `io.Copy` has a fixed buffer which it uses for reading data. But here's the question:

Assuming that I am reading the body of an Http Response which is of type `io.ReadCloser`. And assuming that the output isn't in JSON and it is a RAW binary response. There are two ways to read the content

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer 
_, err := io.Copy(&buffer, res.Body) 
// assuming we checked for error
return buffer.Bytes()
--
bytes, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
// assuming we checked for error
return bytes
```

Now what's the difference between the two. I believe that since I am returning the read bytes, the two approaches are identical. I would like to know if the `io.Copy` approach has any advantage over the other approach in this case at all.

Comment: Use `io.Copy` if you have a need to use a `bytes.Buffer` or some other writer, use `io.ReadAll` if you only need a byte slice. Saying `io.ReadAll` should always be avoided is silly.

Comment: @JimB: That is not my question, my question is `What is the difference between the two methods I provided`. Are they identical?

Comment: No, you asked “Why should io.ReadAll be avoided?”. As for the difference, because `bytes.Buffer` implements `io.ReaderFrom`, they are nearly identical.

Comment: @JimB: Please answer the question by reading it to the end and not by reading the title only. The following link proves there's a difference, but what is that difference? https://daryl-ng.medium.com/why-you-should-avoid-ioutil-readall-in-go-e6be4de180f8

Comment: I did, and because there is so little difference, I assumed you were questioning the premise. Asking to explain the benchmark you didn’t originally provide is another question. The difference likely depends on input size modulo the allocation size, i.e. the difference between `append` and the buffer’s internal grow method. This will probably be different for different inputs. I’m not in a place to do a better benchmark right now, but it shouldn’t be too hard. Also the implementations of `io.ReadAll` and `Buffer.ReadFrom` are easy to inspect.

Comment: "some articles" might be the problem. If this is an article about low level performance tweaking then the advice might make sense. "what's the difference between the two[?]" semantically none. Ignore such articles. Getting code right is often hard enough, getting it right and maintainable even harder. Unless you are _forced_ to tweak the performance: Stop after right, maintainable and fast enough.

Comment: As usual, poor benchmarks are misleading. Unless your program is always decoding json out of a `strings.Reader` of that particular size, the results are meaningless. Modifying the benchmarks to use a file and adjusting the data size will give the edge to `io.ReadAll` in some cases, and make them fairly close in others.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer since I prefer `ReadAll` to `Copy`, but rather an extended comment.

I created 16 MiB (16777216 bytes) `sample.txt` file and used it for benchmark:

```
func BenchmarkReadAll(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        in, _ := os.Open("sample.txt")
        io.ReadAll(in)
        in.Close()
    }
}

func BenchmarkCopy(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
        in, _ := os.Open("sample.txt")
        io.Copy(buf, in)
        in.Close()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org
cpu: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
BenchmarkReadAll-32           26      45445764 ns/op    102635996 B/op        43 allocs/op
BenchmarkXxx-32               48      23985133 ns/op    67108544 B/op         21 allocs/op
```

`ReadAll` has more allocations and, as a result, it consumes more memory in reallocations: to read 16 MiB it allocated/reallocated back and forth 102 MB, 50% more compared to `Copy`.

Still I prefer `ReadAll` for its self-explanatory name. On small files better  name beats lesser performance.